# How to create Index with mapping using new Java Api ElasticSearch(8.0.1)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to create an index in ElasticSearch 8.0.1 with java. The problem is Index is created but the mapping does not. Here is my code;

```
        final RestClient restClient = RestClient
                .builder(new HttpHost(hostName, port, "https"))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider))
                .build();

        final ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

        final ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);

        final JsonpMapper mapper = client._transport().jsonpMapper();

        JsonParser parser = mapper.jsonProvider().createParser(new StringReader(Files.readString(Paths.get(mappingFile), Charsets.UTF_8)));

        
        client.indices().create(builder ->

        builder.index(indexName).mappings(TypeMapping._DESERIALIZER.deserialize(parser, mapper)));
```

When I debug I saw `TypeMapping._DESERIALIZER.deserialize(parser, mapper)` returns null so I assume problem is about my mapping file. When i try to create my index from postman with the same mapping there is no problem. Here is my mapping file;

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "placeOfBirths.country": {
        "type": "text",
        "term_vector": "yes",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "gender": {
        "type": "text",
        "term_vector": "yes",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "deviceId": {
        "type": "text",
        "term_vector": "yes",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are no errors. Just the index has no mappings. What am I missing ?

Comment: I thinck mappings( only expect mappings json, without the settings part.

Comment: tried that. Didnt worked @LeBigCat

Comment: @MEF Did you find a way to make this work?